# How to behave version in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm use the windows platform and padre editor for run the program.

```
use 5.11.0;
```

which version behave like using the `use warnings; use strict;`.
for example

```
use 5.11.0;
$data = 1232;
print $data;
```

Resulting the error is

```
Global symbol "$data" requires explicit package name at file.pl line 2.
Global symbol "$data" requires explicit package name at file.pl line 3.
Execution of t_print.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

In this same error also resulting at when using the `use warnings; use strict;`in the program.

So in every perl program use this version for instead of using `use warnings; use strict;`

Comment: It's the same as `use strict`. You still need to turn on `use warnings` yourself.

Answer (score 3):

This is documented in [use](http://p3rl.org/use):

> use VERSION also enables all features available in the requested version as defined by the `feature` pragma, disabling any features not in the requested version's feature bundle. See [feature](http://p3rl.org/feature). Similarly, if the specified Perl version is greater than or equal to 5.12.0, strictures are enabled lexically as with `use strict`.

Version 5.11 was experimental (it included the changes that led to 5.12). You should only use Perls with even version numbers (5.10, 5.12, ..., 5.20) unless you know exactly why to use a development version.